# Formation of Coordination Compounds

Tags: coordination-compounds

While reading applications of coordination compounds, I read that Hardness of water can be checked using **Na<sub>2</sub>EDTA** in hard water containing **Ca<sup>+2</sup>** and **Mg<sup>+2</sup>** which form complexes with **EDTA**.

Also, Lead (**Pb**), a  p block element is removed by using **EDTA** in case of lead poisoning.

Can elements other than those of d block form complex compounds? Like **Ca(II)** or **Mg(II)**. 
How are such complexes stable?
Can we desrcibe crystal splitting in them?

Comment: I know there are elements not from the d-block that can form coordination complexes. I don't remember exactly which ones (maybe the bigger ones, block p like Al (III), maybe Tl (I), etc., not sure if someones of group II). My initial guess for describing crystal splitting: depends, generally dissolved in water, must consider hydration enthalpy change and lattice energy breaking, etc.

Comment: But which orbitals will split? np orbitals?

Comment: Not sure, that will depend on the theory that describes the orbital overlap: more calssical CFT (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_field_theory) or more quantum- orbital molecular LFT (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligand_field_theory). Elements from 4th period and after [maybe Tl (I, III)?] may have p-d overlaping, thus allowing coordination.

Comment: Most of the transition metal form edta complex. See: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jp904296m